# WLAnalytics not updating on console

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, mobilefirst-server

We are using mobile first for analytics in our application. But the logs are not capturing into the console. Please find my code below:

```
WLAnalytics.enable();

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put("userId", userId);
            json.put("timestamp", Util.getCurrentTimeStamp());
            json.put("os", "Android");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        WLAnalytics.log("{\"package\": \"mfpStart\" }", json);
```

And when I checked the response for anaytics as below:

```
WLRequestListener wlRequestListener = new WLRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(WLResponse wlResponse) {
                Logger.d("MFPLOg", "Analytics res is: "+wlResponse.getResponseText());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(WLFailResponse wlFailResponse) {
                Logger.d("MFPLOg", "Analytics failure res is: "+wlFailResponse.getResponseText());
            }
        };

        WLAnalytics.send(wlRequestListener);
```

Control is going to success callback with response code 201 and response message "". 
And offcourse I am seting the context as like:`WLAnalytics.setContext(getContext());`

Can you please help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check under custom Data (via Custom Charts). The Json data you put will go under the Custom Data and can be accessed via custom charts option.

Comment: Yes KrcKumar, I checked in Custom charts. but analytic messages are not displaying in there.